# How do I control Inheritance with modifiers?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading, access-modifiers

I am basically looking for a way to modify the following source code with modifiers and some extra lines in the method bodies, so it prints out the following in my console:

```
1g
1hb
2f
1g
2hb
1hb
```

Its an exercise for my university classes and i just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Iam only allowed to change the method bodies exept the println-lines as well as changing the modifiers for the methods. How am I supposed to do this and in what relation do the modifiers stand regarding inheritance here? How do I overload the methods to get the desired result?

This is my main method:

```
public class Poly {
     public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Poly1 a = new Poly1();
        a.g();

        Poly2 b = new Poly2();
        b.f();    
    }
}
```

and this is my first class:

```
public class Poly1 {

public void f() {
    System.out.println( "1f" );
    g();
}

private void g() {
    System.out.println( "1g" );
    h( 10 );
}

protected void h( int i ) {
    System.out.println( "1hi" );
}

void h( byte b ) {
    System.out.println( "1hb" );
}
}
```

and the following is my second class:

```
public class Poly2 extends Poly1 {

protected void f() {
    System.out.println( "2f" );
    Poly1 c=new Poly1();
    g();
    h();
}

public void g() {
    System.out.println( "2g" );
    h( 18 );
}

public void h( int i) {
    System.out.println( "2hi" );
}

public void h( byte b ) {
    System.out.println( "2hb" );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Poly1 {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("1f");
        g();
    }

    public void g() {
        System.out.println("1g");
        h((byte) 10); // cast to byte to invoke the overloaded method void
                      // h(byte b)
    }

    protected void h(int i) {
        System.out.println("1hi");
    }

    void h(byte b) {
        System.out.println("1hb");
    }
}


public class Poly2 extends Poly1 {

     public void f() { //change from protected  to public since the visibility of an overidden method Cannot be reduced
        System.out.println("2f");
        Poly1 c = new Poly1();
        c.g(); // invoke the methode g of Poly1
        h((byte) 10);
    }

    public void g() {
        System.out.println("2g");
        h(18);
    }

    protected void h(int i) {
        System.out.println("2hi");
}

    public void h(byte b) {
        System.out.println("2hb");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, that would be basically my solution as well. I just cant get the 2hb in line 5 to work. It somehow has to get in there in between, but i just dont know how?

Comment: super.g(); 
super.h((byte) 10);

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understood super... Cheers!